# How to add CSS file into an iframe in HomePageComponent?

Tags: css, home-page-component

I have to link a css file on home page in customer portal. I want to give this link of css file into home page component, but i am not getting how to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an html home page component you can add the  attribute

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourCssLink"/>
<!--from static resources-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resource/cssFromResource"/>
```